# Do items "found" through Dice Rooms rerolls show as unlocked in the items sheet?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

The only times I've been able to find Dice Rooms with a 1 or 6 face ( that randomly reroll your equipped items) it has been while doing Challenge runs, that don't count in terms of unlocks or achievement. So what I'd like to know is: if my equipment gets rerolled to items I still have to find through normal means, does it counts as found for achievements such as Platinum God? Will it appear on the Items Sheet?

Comment: Probably that's enough to "unlock" them in the Items Sheet, because I've never found a Lucky Foot but Cain starts by default with that item and I can see it in the inventory. Maybe this works with the Dice Room, too.

Comment: I got the achievement *Lord of the Flies* by standing in 1-dice room.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Lord of the Flies is unlocked by simply having both Skatole and Halo of flies on yourself. What I'd like to know is, if I have never found Skatole, for example, and the Dice Room gives me it, will it appear on the Items Sheet?

Comment: @Kappei I've updated my answer, I've found a different response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've asked the [same question](http://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/617321352319553125/) on the SteamCommunity Forum, and this is the outcome:

> Nope, they don't sadly.
>   I know because I've tried it, was getting
>   nothing but Breakfast which meant I had exhausted the entire pool. But
>   none of the items that I needed to find were in the collection page.

EDIT:

There are different opinions, so it's a bit confusing, another guy posted this answer:

> I haven't unlocked these yet and somehow they're there.
>   [image]

Meaning that he hasn't unlocked The Lost items (*The Soul*, *The Body* and *The Mind*) but they are shown in his collection page.
So it appears to be true.

Comment: Your "other guy" has some bug. because even with the d4/ dice rooms you can't roll items you don't have unlocked yet.

Comment: That's weird, the screenshot above is pretty clear, and I don't find a reason to troll people with this kind of lies.